# How to view what materials are using an image?

Tags: materials, image

Some images in my Blender file don't show up in orphan data even though I can't find anything using them. Is there a way to locate what in the Blend file is using the images?

Comment: should be easily doable with a python script.

Comment: Maybe close and reopen the file and this time the images will be removed? They won't be removed at the same session as the materials they are part of but at the next as they are hierarchically below

Comment: Do you want to locate them to get rid of them or for some other reason?

Comment: I want to remove them, but want to make sure they aren't being used for something.